# How to set facebook og:description empty?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following html page which i share on facebook

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="" />
    ...
</head>
...
```

I don't want the `og:description` in my shared link.

When i removed the `og:description` tag, it **filled the description part from my post body**. this also occurred when i set it's value to an **empty string** or **space**.

**How can i make it work with empty `og:description`?**

Answer (score 7):

#### Use HTML Escape Characters

The meta field `og:description` is mandatory. When it's empty the default behavior is to fill it up with text from the page's `<body>`.

However, you can hack it with HTML escape characters:

```
<head>
    ...
    <meta property="og:description" content="&nbsp;" />
    ...
</head>
```

Useful escape characters in this context;

- `&nbsp;` - space
- `&hellip;` - horizontal 3 dots (as [@idomusha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36067922/3191896) suggested, +1)

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="&hellip;" />
```

Comment: Add more information explaining your code. It makes easier for you to earn points on reputation.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup):

> Basic Tags: These are the most basic meta tags that you should use for
>   all content types.

`og:description` is one of them, which is probably why you cannot set it to empty.